# No resource identifier found for attribute 'orientation' in package android

Tags: android

android error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'animation Bitmap Format' in package

```
<com.aphidmobile.flip.FlipViewController
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:flip="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.bhavik.mainStory"
        android:id="@+id/flipView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        flip:orientation="horizontal"
        flip:animationBitmapFormat="RGB_565"
        />
```

Error:Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'orientation' in package 'com.bhavik.mainstory'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'animationBitmapFormat' in package 'com.bhavik.mainstory'

So,Anyone tell me what should I do for resolve this.

Comment: Try to use `xmlns:flip="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`.

Answer (score 0):

write in the AndroidManifiest    android:screenOrientation="landscape"